# Send email using AWS SES from template with custom data and attachment in Spring

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-simple-email-service

I have Spring Boot application and I would like to send email using AWS SES SDK. I have templates for emails (added in SES) with placeholders to put some custom data/strings. Email should also contain attachment (pdf file).

I found this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/69400797/3626048 to load template from SES and use RawEmail to send with attachment (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/javav2-ses-src-main-java-com-example-ses-SendMessageAttachment.java.html). But my problem is that in RawEmail I can't fill placeholders in my templates.

I could find and replace placeholders using String.replaceAll() method but is there any better solution?

Comment: did you solve this? if so can you please share?

Comment: no, finally I used AWS Lambda function for sending emails from template with attachments

Comment: can you share how you solved it with AWS Lambda function? thansk.

Comment: did you pull the pdf file from s3 bucket?

Comment: I don't have access to code anymore but I used S3 to save attachments and `nodemailer` to send emails with attachments in simple way - similiar as described here https://medium.com/@xoor/sending-emails-with-attachments-with-aws-lambda-and-node-js-e6a78500227c